# This LinearLayout should use android:layout_height="wrap_content"?

Tags: android

I have the following xml layout :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:fillViewport="true" >

  <LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent" // ==> here I get the error.
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Test"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
        android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="5dp"  />

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="2dip"
        android:background="#298EB5"
        android:orientation="horizontal" />


  </LinearLayout>
</ScrollView>
```

But I get the lint message :

> This LinearLayout should use android:layout_height="wrap_content"

Why do I get this message?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

`LinearLayout`'s are designed for stacking elements either side by side or on top of each other. My guess is that this lint warning recommends virtical stacking due to the `ScrollView`

[Documentation](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/layout/linear.html):

"All children of a LinearLayout are stacked one after the other, **so a vertical list will only have one child per row**, no matter how wide they are, and a horizontal list will only be one row high (the height of the tallest child, plus padding). A LinearLayout respects margins between children and the gravity (right, center, or left alignment) of each child."

Answer (score 4):

It's not an error but it is not suggested as it will produce unwanted result in some cases. I follow this [article](http://www.curious-creature.org/2010/08/15/scrollviews-handy-trick/) by Romain while using scrollview. I hope this will explain the reason for the message.

Answer (score 3):

its Lint warning you should use

```
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
```

`wrap_content` occupies the height as per the add require content.
Here height of Layout wrap according to require